# c++ Linked List Stack Pop Function Crashing

Tags: c++

I am having the worlds most difficult time understanding this linked list stack. I have been given a fixed ".h" file that I am not allowed to edit, and I am to write the push and pop functions. My pop function, however, is crashing the program and I am unsure why. My pop function is as follows:

```
 int IntStack::pop(){
    int result = -1;
    if(isEmpty()){
        result = head->data; //program crashes here
        Node *temp;
        temp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }
    return result;
}
```

My nodes are the following;

```
struct Node{
     int data;
     Node* next;
};
```

Any insight as to why this is crashing and how I can fix it would be appreciated. Also, I am not allowed to have a parameter in the function. Thank you

EDIT: I made the changes suggested to the function, and here is the rest of my code.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>
 #include "IntStack.h"

 using namespace std;

 bool ArePair(int first,char last){
     if(first == '(' && last == ')') return true;
     else if(first == '{' && last == '}') return true;
     else if(first == '[' && last==']') return true;
     return false;
 }

 int main(){
     string fileName;

     cout << "Hello, please enter a filename: ";
     cin >> fileName;

     ifstream inFile;

     inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

     while (!inFile){
         cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open " << fileName << ". Please re-enter.\n";
         cin >> fileName;
         inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
     }

     string current;
     IntStack iStack;
     int par; //parenthesis

     while(inFile){
        inFile >> current;

        for(int i=0;i<current.length();i++){
             if(current[i] == '('||current[i] == '{'||current[i] == '['){
                 par = current[i];
                 iStack.push(par);
                }
             else if(current[i] == ')'||current[i] == '}'||current[i] == ']'){
                 if(!iStack.isEmpty() || !ArePair(par,current[i])){
                     cout << "debug\n";
                 }
                 else{
                    iStack.pop();
                 }
             }
         }
     }



     inFile.close();

 }
```

I think i may have an invalid pointer on the head of my pop function, but i am unsure. Or perhaps its my push function?

```
 void IntStack::push(int data){
     assert(!isFull());
         Node *temp = new Node;
         temp->data = data;
         temp->next = NULL;
         temp = head;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: `assert(isEmpty());`doesn't look like a good precondition when trying to remove an element.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do in that code exactly? You could've just done `int result = head->data;` instead of the whole rigamarole with temp, which you just remove in the end. Also I reckon you never really remove head the way I suppose you want to.

I'm guessing this is what you were asking about:

```
int IntStack::pop(){ 
   int result = -1;             //Assume there is no element to pop
   if(!this->isEmpty()){        //if the stack is not empty,
        result = head->data;    //save the head's data in result
        Node *temp;             //make a temp node
        temp = head->next;      //point it to the node after the head
        delete head;            //remove the head
        head = temp;            //make the one after it the new head
    }
    return result;              //return the result
}
```

EDIT:

You're missing the head node and the tail node in your code.
When you have the tail node, the push should look like this:

```
 void IntStack::push(char data){
     if(!this->isFull()){
         Node *temp = new Node;
         temp->data = data;
         tail->next = temp;
         temp->next = NULL;
     }
 }
```

`ArePair` has a loose return at the end you ought to regulate like this:

```
 bool ArePair(int first, char last){
     if((first == '(' && last == ')') ||
        (first == '{' && last == '}') ||
        (first == '[' && last == ']'))
          return true;
     else return false;
 }
```

I think you'll find this more useful since you know the rest of your code yourself, and there are some basic constructs to cover here.
https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/a-comprehensive-guide-to-implementation-of-singly-linked-list-using-c_plus_plus-ondlm5azr

Comment: I tried implementing the code you offered, but still the function crashes the program and im not quite sure why. Also, im trying to create a program that reads in a file, stores brackets in a stack, and pops them whenever a matching closing bracket is read.

Comment: ``par = current[i];`` is trying to assign a char to an int, also why are you assigning the newest node(when pushing) as the head every time after you set the data? that will overwrite the new node with the head

Comment: When i push in a char, i believe it converts it to an int. I may be wrong, i just remember reading that in a forum. Furthermore, i pulled out the head assignment as you suggested but alas i cant keep it running.

Comment: Yes it does convert it to an int, though it suggests there might be a conversion error in your "real" code you missed as a result. I'll put a useful link in the answer, the code needs an overhaul, and since you have full access to all of your code, you'll do it best.